# Which lens to purchase with canon 550d

Tags: canon-550d

hi I have canon 550D and have 2 leses 18-55 / 55-250; going thru the sharpness and quality i am thinking to purchase 40mm / 50mm lense. as per me the quality of images of existing lenses are not that much sharp what it needs to be.

Can anybody advice me
(1) Is it right to go for 40mm / 50mm lense
(2) if yes, which one?

Answer (score -1):

This will always be down to personal opinion, but I'd say you cannot go wrong with a 50mm prime lens.  The 1.8 is very good and a very cheap option, but if you can stretch to the f/1.4 version, it rocks, and is VERY sharp.